# initialize decision variables in GAMS in form of a set + equation gives errors

Tags: optimization, gams-math

I am trying to model a problem using GAMS. I have 2 questions:

1) How to initialize the decesion value P? it supose to be in the following form

P(I)/

i1 25

i2 33
/

2) I am trying to calculate SINR as in

SINR(I) =e= hh(I)*P(I) / sqr(sigma)+sum(I,H(J,I)*P(I));

However, I got always an erro either the set is already controller or domain isssues. How can I solve this problem?

Part of the CODE

> set
>
> I number of users    /i1,i2/
>
> J users to interfer with  /j1,j2/
>
> iteration number of iterations  /1/ ;
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> CP(I) circuit power per user  /
>
> i1  10
>
> i2  10 /
> hh(I)  channel quality  /    i1  48    i2  106 /
> Sigma    Noise              /0.0057/
> tol      tolerence value    /0.01/
> minRate  minimum rate /0.1/
>
> maxiter max number of iterations /3/   ;
> ```

```
Table H(J,I) interference value

>        i1          i2
>
>  j1    0         18.8030
> 
>  j2    8.9555         0
```

;
>

> Variables
>
> ```
> P(I)
>
> F
>
> lambda
>
> SINR(I)
>
> b(I)
>
> a(I)
> ```
>
> equations   Objectivefun, SINRFUN, lambdaFUN, RateFUN, afun, bfun,
>   nonlconfun;
>
> SINRFUN(I)..       SINR(I) =e= hh(I)*P(I) /
>   sqr(sigma)+sum(I,H(J,I)*P(I));

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
SINRFUN(I).. SINR(I) =e= hh(I)*P(I) / sqr(sigma)+sum(I,H(J,I)*P(I));
```

has a problem we have an implicit loop over `i` and then inside a sum over the same `i`. This is mathematically not very well defined. So you could do something like:

```
alias(i,ii);
SINRFUN(I).. SINR(I) =e= hh(I)*P(I) / sqr(sigma)+sum(ii,H(J,ii)*P(ii));
```

You can initialize `P(i)` with an assignment statement:

```
parameter initp(i) /i1 25, i2 33/;
p.L(i) = initp(i);
```

The `.L` means we assign to the level values of the variables (other possibilities are things like`.lo`, `.up`, `.m`: see the documentation for more information -- reading some docs may be beneficial in any case).

Comment: I fix the frist statement thank you very much. Unfortunately, the second part did not work but the hint helped me to find out how to solve it. Thank you again :)